# Property of uniformly tight random variables?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm stumped on the following question, which is problem 1.3.9 in the book *Weak Convergence and Empirical Proceses* by van der Vaart and Wellner. It is based on the following notion of asymptotic tightness:

> **Definition**: A sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ taking values in a metric space with metric $d$ is asymptotically tight if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a compact $K_0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ we have $\varliminf_{n \to \infty} P(X_n \in K_0^\delta) \ge 1 - \epsilon$ where $K_0^\delta = \{x: d(x, K_0) < \delta\}$ is the $\delta$-enlargement of $K_0$.

For convenience, the definition of uniform tightness is

> **Definition**: A sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is uniformly tight if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a compact $K$ such that $P(X_n \in K) \ge 1 - \epsilon$ for every $K$.

The problem is:

> **Claim**:  A sequence $X_n$ is uniformly tight if and only if it is asymptotically tight and each $X_n$ is tight.

I cannot seem to prove the non-trivial direction of this claim. The following hint is given:

> **Hint**: Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Take a compact $K_0$ with $\varliminf P(X_n \in K_0^\delta) \ge 1 - \epsilon$ for every $\delta$. Choose $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots $ such that $P(X_n \in K_0^{1/m}) \ge 1 - 2 \epsilon$ for $n \ge n_m$. For $n_m < n  \le n_{m+1}$ choose a compact $K_n$ with $P(X_n \in K_0^{1/m} - K_n) < \epsilon$. Now $K = \bigcup_{n = 0} ^ \infty K_n$ is compact and $P(X_n \in K) \ge 1 - 3 \epsilon$.

Now, I understand everything in the hint except for the claim that $K = \bigcup_{n = 0} ^ \infty K_n$ is compact. I assume I'm missing something in how $K_n$ is constructed that makes the countable union compact, since obviously a countable union of compact sets isn't necessarily compact. I also can't seem to find a proof of this claim anywhere other than this book, except a proof in the book *Introduction to Empirical Processes and Semiparametric Inference* which apparently just copies this hint and leaves the claim that $K$ is compact as "an exercise left to the reader."

**EDIT**: I think I have a sketch now for compactness, so if anyone could verify it I would be appreciative. The $K_n$ can be chosen so that $K_0 \subseteq K_n \subseteq K_0^{1/m}$ for $n_m < n \le n_{m+1}$. Given an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $K$, find a finite subcover of $K_0$, $U_1, \ldots, U_K$. Next, find $m$ such that $K_0^{1/m} \subseteq \bigcup_{k = 1} ^K U_k$ (exists because $K_0$ is compact and $\bigcup_{k = 1} ^ K U_k$ is open). Hence $U_1, \ldots, U_K$ is an open cover for $K_n$ for all $n > n_m$. Now, just use compactness of $K_1, \ldots, K_{n_m}$ extend the open cover $K_{n_m + 1}, K_{n_m + 2}, \ldots$ to one which covers all $K_n$.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way to show the non-trivial direction of the posted claim is the follwoing.

Since the sequence of random variables is asymptotically tight, we have that there is some $n^*$ such that, for all $n>n^*$, $\sup_{k\ge n}P(X_n\notin K)<\epsilon$. Uniform tightness thus follows by combining this result with the fact that the collection $(X_1,...,X_{n^*})$ is finite and the fact that every finite collection of tight random variables is also tight.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It has been a long time so I am a little bit hazy, but how do you know there exists an $n^*$ with this property? If I remember correctly, this property is *stronger* than asymptotic tightness; for asymptotic tightness we can only guarantee an $n^\star$ such that $\sup_{k \ge n} P(X_n \notin K^\delta) \le \epsilon$ for a $\delta$-enlargement of $K$, and I vaguely recall that Van der Vaart and Wellner explicitly state that you cannot prove equivalence between these properties.